# analog clock's hand isn't rotating

Tags: javascript, html, css

[clock face](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1y7j.jpg)

I'm trying to make an analog clock using js/css/html .

The thing is that the clock's hand isn't working.

Rotating it from inside the js function dosn't seem to work. I tried changing the rotation degree manually from css, it worked.

The function is working I tried console-login the value of the seconds,  it worked.

```js
function ticktock() {
  var time = new Date();
  var second = time.getSeconds();
  document.getElementsByClassName("clock-hand")[0].style.tranform = 'rotate(54deg)';
  console.log(second);
  setTimeout(ticktock, 1000);
}
ticktock();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px solid green;
  position: relative;
}

.clock {
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1y7j.jpg);
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-size: cover;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  position: relative;
}

.clock-hand {
  position: absolute;
  top: 49px;
  left: 51px;
  border: 2px solid violet;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="clock-style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>time teller</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="clock">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0zgO.png" alt="clock-hand" class="clock-hand">

    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.8.0/p5.js">
  </script>
  <script src="clock-logic.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

[clock hand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0zgO.png)

Comment: It's simply a typo, change`tranform` to `transform` and it will work,

Comment: On another note, is there a reason you run the `setTimeout()` in the `ticktock()` function? This'll create a new timeout on each tick. Why not [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)?

Comment: First of all, thanks for the help, and to answer lewis, i tried to use setInterval but after few seconds it seems to speed up ,i'm not really sure but i think because everytime, it executes over the one before, wich kinda breaks the clock, here is a Reddit  article that might help ... https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/47egqf/setinterval_going_crazy_cant_figure_it_out/

Comment: It's just a typo. Change ` document.getElementsByClassName("clock-hand")[0].style.tranform = 'rotate(54deg)';` to `document.getElementsByClassName("clock-hand")[0].style.transform = 'rotate( ' + second  + 'deg)';` Ref: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yrRrvG

Answer (score 1):

I voted to close the question because the issue is only a typo, but I still wanted to post this snippet with a working seconds hand as I had done it anyway...

```js
function ticktock() {
  var time = new Date();
  var second = time.getSeconds();
  document.getElementsByClassName("clock-hand")[0].style.transform = 'rotate(' + (second/60*360) + 'deg)';
  console.log(second);
  setTimeout(ticktock, 1000);
}
ticktock();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px solid green;
  position: relative;
}

.clock {
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1y7j.jpg);
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-size: cover;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  position: relative;
}

.clock-hand {
  position: absolute;
  top: 49px;
  left: 51px;
  border: 2px solid violet;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="clock-style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>time teller</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="clock">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0zgO.png" alt="clock-hand" class="clock-hand">

    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.8.0/p5.js">
  </script>
  <script src="clock-logic.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```